# Запуск python файла через bat-ник с подключением библиотек

Tags: python, pyqt5, bat

Мой проект был написан в Pycharm, а следовательно виртуальное пространство было создано автоматический (vevn). Основной рабочий файл main.py, а библиотеки, которые я использую PyQt5 и requests.

Я накидал такой код в bat-нике:

```
@echo off
%~dp0vevn\Scripts\activate.bat
python %~dp0main.py
%~dp0vevn\Scripts\deactivate.bat
```

В теории он должен был работать. активирую виртуалку по абсолютному пути, запускаю main.py, и после деактивирую виртуалку.

После запуска от имени админа, на мгновение открывается консоль, но ничего не происходит. Через pause, понял, что строка `python %~dp0main.py` не работает.

Вопрос: почему и как это исправить?

Comment: %~dp0 - вернёт полный путь, ОТКУДА запущен батник   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112055/what-does-d0-mean-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: @Виктор знаю, спасибо, поэтому и использовал его. У меня исполняемый bat файл находится в том же месте где и main.py. Активация виртуального пространства находится в здесь же, но нужно еще зайти в папку vevn\Scripts и активировать ее. Первая и последняя строчка кода работает, а вот вторая нет :\

Comment: Используйте call %~dp0vevn\Scripts\activate.bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сработало Ваше решение, необходимо вызывать bat файл через call. Простой запуск bat файла - создаётся свой контекст:

```
@echo off
call %~dp0vevn\Scripts\activate.bat
python %~dp0main.py
call %~dp0vevn\Scripts\deactivate.bat
```

Вывод для моего случая:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2251]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation). Все права защищены.

C:\Projects\QT\taskWinUI>b.bat

C:\Projects\QT\taskWinUI>echo C:\Projects\QT\taskWinUI
C:\Projects\QT\taskWinUI\

C:\Projects\QT\taskWinUI>call C:\Projects\QT\taskWinUI\Scripts\activate.bat

Being destroyed

(taskWinUI) C:\Projects\QT\taskWinUI>

^^^^^^^^- указывет нам, что venv запустился

Comment: Избегайте отвечать одним только кодом, нужен также поясняющий текст в ответе - в чём его суть хотя бы вкратце

Comment: После выполнение данного кода выдается такая ошибка:
```Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "{path}\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'```
Следовательно, виртуально пространство не создается

Comment: Перед последним call поставьте rem - и увидите, если скрипт запустился - то (...) будет. Запускаю у себя - всё работает

Comment: Я не сразу понял, что нужно запускать батник через консоль :Р
На этот раз все работает. Спасибо!)